# Cleanse survey data and sum the responses to be in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, survey

Columns of my dataframe are the survey questions and the rows are the responses. The unique response choices were (1 - Strong Disagree, 2 - Disagree, 3 - Neutral, 4- Agree, 5- Strongly Agree). The rows have all the respondents selections and I ideally would like the columns to be the unique response choices with a sum of how many people selected that response per question and the rows to be each question.

Not sure how to get that - any suggestions?

My original data
[image: My original data]

Tried to transpose which successfully made the questions rows but now I have 100s of unique "rows" for each response
[image: Tried to transpose which successfully made the questions rows but now I have 100s of unique "rows" for each response]

Ultimate goal would be to group-by the questions and have the response choices under each question with the columns as a sum for each response
[image: Ultimate goal would be to group-by the questions and have the response choices under each question with the columns as a sum for each response]

Comment: Hey! The pictures were useful. I've answered something which is similar to the shape you're after. Hope it help! :)

Comment: Thank you!! This worked perfectly and then I added a group-by at the end to get the ultimate goal view :)

Comment: awesome! Np :) if you don’t mind me asking, how did you use a group by to get to the final view?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit quick and dirty but it might help

**EDIT** Updated to transform the tally into a pandas data frame

Setup example dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame ({ 'question_1' : ['1 - strongly agree','1 - strongly agree','2 - agree'], 
                     'question_2' : ['3 - neutral','2 - agree','2 - agree'],
                     'question_3' : ['1 - strongly agree','2 - agree','3 - neutral'],
                     'question_4' : ['4 - disagree','5 - strongly disgree','5 - strongly disgree'],
                     'question_5' : ['3 - neutral','2 - agree','2 - agree']} )
```

Get the value_counts() for each column

```
ls_flat = []
for col in  df.columns:
    for index in df[col].value_counts().index:
        print(col,index, df[col].value_counts()[index])
        ls_flat.append([col,index, df[col].value_counts()[index]])
```

Make this list into a dataframe

```
df_flat = pd.DataFrame(ls_flat)
```

Rename columns to something more meaningful

```
df_flat.columns = ['question', 'response', 'tally']
```

This will create a dataframe which looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final result with your code and the group-by!
[final results!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WsmR.png)

Comment: We played - straight forward